# Sorting an int array from highest to lowest

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I just learned about the `Arrays.sort(arrayName);` and applied it in a project of mine but I found it sorts from lowest to highest. Is there anyway to have it do the opposite? (I don't think I need to post the code in question but if it is needed I'll post it).

Comment: You'll notice there's another `sort` method that accepts a `Comparator`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Not to sort an `int[]`.

Comment: Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[], java.util.Comparator)

Comment: @Jon There's an exercise for OP.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's not an exercise, I would find it as a limitation of `Arrays` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use an `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`, then you can pass a `Comparator` as 2nd argument to the sort method. To impose reverse ordering, you can make use of [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29) method:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have an `int[]` array, you can sort it using `Arrays.sort` and then reverse it :

```
int [] tab2 = new int[]{1,5,0,-2};
Arrays.sort(tab2);
ArrayUtils.reverse(tab2);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(tab2));
```

Output :

```
[5, 1, 0, -2]
```

[`Code`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.java#ArrayUtils.reverse%28int%5B%5D%29) of the reverse method (from [`org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.reverse(int[])`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#reverse%28int%5b%5d%29)) :

```
public static void reverse(int[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return;
        }
        int i = 0;
        int j = array.length - 1;
        int tmp;
        while (j > i) {
            tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;
            j--;
            i++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some usecases you may come along by just treating your sorted array as "reverse sorted". E.g. to iterate from highest to lowest number you may use

```
int[] foo = ...;
Arrays.sort(foo);
for (int i=foo.length-1; i>=0; i--) { 
  doSomethingWith(foo[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use an `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`
2. Make use of [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29): Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering on a collection of objects that implement the Comparable interface
3. If possible use `ArrayList<Integer>` and `Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder())` for stronger case.

   ```
   Integer[] intArr = new Integer[10];
    // add some integer 
   Arrays.sort(intArr, Collections.reverseOrder())
   ```